# Wix Bootstrapper will not update, Error 0x800705b4

Tags: wix, updates, bootstrapper, failed-installation

I have a Wix Bootstrapper which installs/updates a number of MSIs. The MSI runs and updates fine, and the Bootstrapper will run fine for an initial install. I attempted to test Updating with the Boostrapper, however, and every time it will not even launch, and spawn a large number of processes and Setup_XXXXXXXXXXXXX_Failed.txt files in the %Temp% folder. each of these failed.txt files contain the following at the end:

[3098:23F8][2014-06-10T11:03:00]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to open parent pipe: \.\pipe\BurnPipe.{087217E1-A4F3-4951-8319-06031945DA08}
[3098:23F8][2014-06-10T11:03:00]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to connect to unelevated process.
[3098:23F8][2014-06-10T11:03:00]e000: Error 0x800705b4: Failed to run per-machine mode

The numbers vary between files but the errors remain the same.

I am running this Bootstrapper Exe with various command line arguments to tell it what MSIs to install and to provide it with Install Location and various arguments for Custom Actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was reported at http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3890/.  I just recently fixed it, the next WiX build shouldn't spawn a large number of processes.

However, the underlying problem was that Burn was receiving a command line that [`CommandLineToArgvW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) couldn't parse.  You need to make sure that all double quotes are properly escaped, and that when using double quotes for spaces that there is an even number of them.

Comment: the following string is what I am passing via commandline:

 /i INSTALLCW6=1 ORC=0 JOBS=0 ROUTE=0 ACTG=1 DONOTMSMQ=0 CUSTCODE=MAFL SERVER=NickWin8 DBNAME=MAFLTrany INSTALLFOLDER="C:\Users\nickd\Desktop\WixTestingInstall" UPDATEDATE="6/10/2014 12:05:14 PM" INSTALLTYPE="update" USEINTEGRATEDSECURITY=0 APPENDWILDCARD=1

I do not see any double quotes that are not properly escaped

Comment: @downeysyndrome By my count, that's 257 characters.  Depending on how you're calling your Exe, you might be running into a limit on how long the command line can be.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I have a .net app which passes the .exe all of this data, and it pulls INSTALLFOLDER from a registry key, and if InstallFolder's path ends in a "\" (which the registry key adds), then it fails. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This just helped me resolve an issue with the Visual Studio 2017 RC installer.